# Run parallel Protractor tests in multiple Chrome tabs

Tags: selenium, protractor, chrome-web-driver

I'm using the following .conf:

```
capabilities: {
    browserName : 'chrome',
    shardTestFiles: true,
    'time-zone': 'AEST',
    maxInstances: 5,
    singleWindow: true
}
```

I'm using `singleWindow` as described in the [capabilities page](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/DesiredCapabilities) for Selenium and the properties are passed to the WebDriver according to [this](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/browser-setup.md#using-multiple-browsers-in-the-same-test). However I'm still seeing multiple individual windows appearing and disappearing during execution. These fight for focus and it's very annoying while doing other work.

Is it possible to run parallel tests in separate tabs rather than separate instances/windows of Chrome?